# Child element does not counter-skew when it's supposed to

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation bar that I want to skew, but just the bar and not the words of the bar.
So, I skewed the main div (of the navigation bar), and skewed the negative value of it to the text.

However, the text still does not un-skew.

How does this work?

```css
body
   {
   background-color: rgb(21,14,43);
   background-image: url("../images/backgroundimage.jpg");
   background-size: cover;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-attachment: fixed;
   min-height: 100%;
   background-position: center center;
   overflow: hidden;
   }
 
#navbarbox   
   {
   clear: both;
   display: block;
   width: 80vw;
   height: 3.5vw;
   margin: auto;
   padding: 0.5vw 0 0 0;
   }
#navbar, #navbar ul
   {
   width: 70vw;
   height: 3.5vw;
   display: flex;
   padding: 0 0 0 0;
   }
   
#navbar span
   {
   height: 3.5vw;
   transform: skewX(15deg); /*This is supposed to un-skew, but doesn't work!*/
   }
   
#navbar li
   {
   color: white;
   list-style: none;
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 0.8vw 3vw 0 3vw;
   text-align: center;
   color: red;
   font-size: 2vw;
   font-family: Jura;
   height: 2.5vw;
   transform: skewX(-15deg);
      background-color: green;
   }
```

```html
<!--navigation barrrrrr-->
<div id="navbarbox">
 <ul id="navbar">
  <a href="default.html"><li style="background-color: purple;"><span>Home</span></li></a>
  <a href="servers.html"><li id="server"><span>Servers</span></li></a>
  <a href="community.html"><li id="community"><span>Community</span></li></a>
  <a href="store.html"><li id="store"><span>Store</span></li></a>
  <a href="downloads.html"><li id="downloads"><span>Downloads</span></li></a>
  <a href="contact.html"><li id="contact"><span>Contact</span></li></a>
 </ul>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transformation has no affect on your `span` element because it is being displayed as `inline`. You need to set it to display as a block:

```css
#navbar span {
  display: block; /* or inline-block */
}
```

```css
body
   {
   background-color: rgb(21,14,43);
   background-image: url("../images/backgroundimage.jpg");
   background-size: cover;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-attachment: fixed;
   min-height: 100%;
   background-position: center center;
   overflow: hidden;
   }
 
#navbarbox   
   {
   clear: both;
   display: block;
   width: 80vw;
   height: 3.5vw;
   margin: auto;
   padding: 0.5vw 0 0 0;
   }
#navbar, #navbar ul
   {
   width: 70vw;
   height: 3.5vw;
   display: flex;
   padding: 0 0 0 0;
   }
   
#navbar span
   {
            display: block;
   height: 3.5vw;
   transform: skewX(15deg);
   }
   
#navbar li
   {
   color: white;
   list-style: none;
   display: inline-block;
   padding: 0.8vw 3vw 0 3vw;
   text-align: center;
   color: red;
   font-size: 2vw;
   font-family: Jura;
   height: 2.5vw;
   transform: skewX(-15deg);
      background-color: green;
   }
```

```html
<!--navigation barrrrrr-->
<div id="navbarbox">
 <ul id="navbar">
  <a href="default.html"><li style="background-color: purple;"><span>Home</span></li></a>
  <a href="servers.html"><li id="server"><span>Servers</span></li></a>
  <a href="community.html"><li id="community"><span>Community</span></li></a>
  <a href="store.html"><li id="store"><span>Store</span></li></a>
  <a href="downloads.html"><li id="downloads"><span>Downloads</span></li></a>
  <a href="contact.html"><li id="contact"><span>Contact</span></li></a>
 </ul>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you! I was wondering what I've been doing wrong